# How do i count members of a list in wxmaxima?

Tags: arraylist, maxima, wxmaxima

In wxmaxima, for my assignment I was given a list exp.
L:[1,-2,3,4,-5,11,-12]

I need to count members of the list that are less than 0, print that data and print such members. I used:

```
L:[1,-2,3,4,-5,11,-12]$
n: length(L)$
for k:1 thru n step 1 do
if L[k]<0 then print(L[k]);
```

and I got:

```
-2
-5
-12
done
```

My question is, how do I get the number of members,which in this example would be 3, printed?

Comment: There are different ways to go about it, but a simple way is to say `foo: sublist(L, P)` where P is a predicate function, and then say `length(foo)`. A suitable predicate is, for example, `lambda([x], x < 0)`.